# Why didn't Ban look for Elaine instead of staying in prison?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In "The Seven Deadly Sins", after the Sins were branded as traitors and the holy knights took over, they each went their separate ways and into hiding. Ban was imprisoned eventually. He stayed there for years even though he could escape. He only got out when he got the word the Meliodas was out and looking for them.

Ever since he came out, he's been trying to look for a way to revive Elaine. I was wondering why he stayed in the prison for so long if he still had such an important thing to do. Why waste all that time when he could have looked for finding a way to revive her.

Answer (score 1):

When Ban escapes from prison he explains that he allowed himself to be imprisoned because back then he craved pain.  This gave him, in a twisted way, pleasure but he grew tired of it. When he heard Meliodas was nearby, he escaped because following him would be more fun than being locked in a cell with bars through his limbs barely being fed.

It takes visiting the after life, having his team fight the resurrected Helbram, and fighting with Captain to decide to go out on his own to resurrect her.  He is obviously more than willing to take any opportunity to bring her back (even betraying his team) if he observes an opportunity.  This seems to indicate that he gave up for a while and did not pursue that goal because he did not know how to bring her back. He didn't seem to have a known way to bring her back but since going off on his own, he has started to search desperately.  I would expect he did the same before going to prison.

Keep in mind that, for an immortal man and long-lived fairies, 5 years isn't a very long time (even though it took much less time to fall for each other).  This was almost like taking a (pleasant?) vacation when he had no clear time constraint on his project despite it's obvious importance to him.  I would assume their was some guilty and self-contempt involved too.

Comment: I doubt that Ban could ever even think of relaxing and slacking off just because he is immortal and has all the time in the world. After the Sins were branded traitors and hunted, he had absolutely nothing to do. Now that he is out, he even leaves the Sins just to look for Elaine. If he is really that desperate, why would he waste so much time in the first place.
It seems to me that Ban knew about the "Horn of Cernunnos". Why wouldn't he look for it when he knew there was a way to revive Elaine?
I believe there might be better answers, so I guess I'll wait a little longer. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it ties in with the fact that he wasn't looking for a way to revive her back before they were disbanded. It seemed as if he was looking for a way to keep her off his mind, while we tries to keep himself together. I agree with you though, it does seem a bit out of character if he were to be relaxing and slacking off. I believe at some point he does mention that being with Meliodas did help him keep his mind off of Elaine and helped him get himself together.

Also as a side note, being part of the 7 Deadly Sins was a huge time commitment. He probably did not have enough time to go looking around for the "Horn of Cernunnos". It would also make sense that he avoided the Horn if he knew it was in the Capital since he is wanted. As for why he locked himself up instead of looking for alternatives ways? It could just go back to getting himself together and being in the right mental state to cope with his loss. Ban is surprisingly very nonchalant when it comes to all of this, and it could be an effect of him training himself during this time.